# R: Using RegExp (JavaScript) in R with PCRE

Tags: regex, r

There are a couple of websites that are very handy when it comes to regular expressions, such as [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/), however the given example uses JavaScript's RegEx and RegExp and is (afaik) not compatible with R.

Is there a package where we can use RegEx or RegExp in R? Or convert the commands to an R-compatible format? Or do we have a site where we can interactively build regex for r or test expressions that work in R (preferably for free)?

Thank you very much for any hint of a direction!

Furthermore, I am aware of `gsub` and the other options for regular expressions in R (`help("regex")`). However, I find it quite complicated finding the right expression and would like to find an easier solution to it.

## Added Example:

To give an example: Another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088964/parsing-dates-from-text-in-r) asked for a complex, at least not trivial regex-function, which got me curious. Using [regexr.com (with example)](http://regexr.com/3cbj8), I was able to find the PCRE expression for it, which looks like this: `/( [J, F, M, A, S, O, N, D])\w+ [1-31][th, st]\w+, [0-2100]\w+ /g`. I am explicably not looking for a translation to the specific r regex, but a way to translate it or use the the PCRE-code in R.

```
reg <- "( [J, F, M, A, S, O, N, D])\\w+ [1-31][th, st]\\w+, [0-2100]\\w+"

# simulate some data
set.seed(123)
months <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
            "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")

day <- round(runif(12, 1, 28), 0)
dates <- paste0(months," ", day, ifelse(day==1, "st", "th"), ", 2015") # leaving out "nd" and "rd" for arbitrary reasons

texts <- paste0("Some random text with a date, ", dates, 
                " - and some other, non-use dates, ",
                months, " 2015")
texts[1]
# [1] "Some random text with a date, January 9th, 2015 - and some other, non-use dates, January 2015"

# expected result: January 9th, 2015
# but
grep(reg, texts[1], perl = T, value = T)
# character(0)
```

Now the question is: How can I use the expression `reg` in R; Do I need to transform it so it is changed to an R-regex? Or is there another way to achieve it.

Comment: Did you even try to google "r regex" ?

Comment: I am aware that we have something like `gsub` where we can use our own regex. But as I wrote in the question, I am looking for a tool to make it easier to build an expression!

Comment: or try `help("regex")`

Comment: `help("regex")` doesn't resolves the issue. As I am looking for a way to use the code I constructed using regexr.com in R.

Comment: R should support all the ERE and PCRE regexes (http://regex101.com php). So no need for separate r regex site.

Comment: Thanks, @AvinashRaj for pointing me in the right direction. I've added an example to the question to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Google is your very best friend.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html

Also, http://regex101.com allows you to pick the "PCRE" flavor of regex, which is what R uses if you use the perl=TRUE parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the comment... But this is not what I am looking for.
Either I am looking for a way to use the code from regexr.com in R or a tool that translates it or one that is interactive (ok, I didn't specify that I don't want to pay 30€ for it)

Comment: My link describes exactly how to use regex in R...  I'm confused as to what you're after.

Comment: Have you tried https://regex101.com ?  You should be able to use regexes built there in your R code.

Comment: That definately helps, but where is the difference between regex101 and regexr? If you change your answer to that I will give an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Several of the sites listed under Processing Tools near the bottom of this page: https://code.google.com/p/gsubfn/ support Perl (also called PCRE) and perl/pcre is also supported by various R regular expression functions using the argument `perl = TRUE`.    See the analyzer, debuggex, regex101 sites and possibly others there.

Comment: Thats more what I am looking for.
One quesition though, say that I have a code like this: `/([0-9])\w+ /g`, how would I be able to get all numbers out of the text: `grep("/([0-9])\\w+ /g", "test 123 test 3", perl = T, value = T)` returns `character(0)`.

Comment: Can use `regmatches` or relavent functions in stringr or gsubfn.  In gsubfn it would be:  `library(gsubfn); strapplyc(x, "\\d+", simplify = c)` where `x` is the input.  The gsubfn home page referred to in my answer has a lot of relevant regular expression links.

Comment: I updated the question and added an example/code. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: The original question was where to find a site that can be used to test R regular expressions and now it's been completely changed.  I think you need to post a new question if that is no longer your question.